# React App not loading, showing "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'" in console, but works in Private Window

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have browsed many possible solutions to this error with no success. I understand the fundamental issue is that the request to `/static/js/main.[hash].js` is expecting JS, and instead is returning HTML. I can not, however, understand why the application runs fine while using a Private window, and also will work ONE time after clearing cache and hard reload. In addition to the error message, we get a white screen and the app does not load.

Looking at the Network tab in the browser, I compared the request when working and when not working. I noticed that when working, i.e. in private window, it seems as though the HTML is fetched using a different endpoint, `/null`. The response is the same HTML that causes the error (the app HTML), but for some reason it works here.

It seems as though the error could be fixed if I could define the request to accept HTML or JSX, but I don't know where to find where this request is called as it seems as though this is all handled by Webpack.

One thing to note, is that when running `yarn build` and serving the build locally, we still get the error message, but the app does load (no white screen). In the local build HTML, we find a script tag like this:

`<script src="undefined"></script>`

While the production (breaking) build gives us this:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/main.ff34f559.js"></script>`

edit: The project was created using CRA then freshly ejected

Any help is greatly appreciated!